# Two functions, one having a modulus and taking their Wronskian. (DE)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the two functions: $f(x)=x^3$ and $g(x)=x^2 |x|$ on the interval [-1,1]

(a) Show that their Wronskian $W(f,g)$ vanishes identically.

**My attempt:**
$$W(y_1,y_2)=y_1y_2'-y_2y_1'$$
I am not sure how to take the derivative of the absolute value function? I know it is not possible as it has a "sharp" point. So, I decided to consider two cases:
Case 1: $x\ge 0$:
So $g(x)=x^3$
$$W(f,g) =x^3*3x^2-x^3*3x^2=0$$ and so identically zero everywhere.
Case 2: $x\le 0$: So $g(x)=-x^3$
$$W(f,g)=x^3*(-3x^2)+x^3*3x^2=-3x^5+3x^5=0$$

So is this method valid?

Now part (b) is where I am confused:

"Show that $f$ and $g$ are not linearly dependent."

Well I studied that if $W=0$ then they should be linearly dependent. Here is requires to show otherwise, any hints/ideas?

Moreover, part (c) asks if (a) and (b) contradicts the the following lemma:

**Lemma.** If $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$ are two solutions of
$$y''+P(x)y′+Q(x)y=0$$
on $[a,b]$, then they are linearly dependent on this interval if and only if their  Wronskian $W(y_1,y_2)$=$y_1y_2'−y_2y_1'$ is identically zero.

**Proof of lemma.**
Assume $y_1$ and $y_2$ are linearly dependent first, then we show as a consequence of this that the Wronskian is zero. Also assume neither function is identically zero, as this is a trivial case. So we have $y_2=cy_1$ and substituting into the Wronskian indeed yields 0.

Now the other half of the lemma:

Assume the Wronskian is identically zero and we want to prove that the solutions must be linearly dependent. Assume $y_1$ does not vanish identically on $[a,b]$, from which it follows by continuity that $y_1$ does not vanish at all on some subinterval $[c,d]$ of $[a,b]$. Since the Wronskian is identically zero on $[a,b]$, we can divide by $y_1^2$ to get:
$$\frac{y_1y_2'-y_2y_1'}{y_1^2}=0 $$
**On [c,d]**
Then,
$$\int(\frac{y_2}{y_1})' = \int 0 dx $$
Yielding, $$  y_2=ky_1 \space\space\space \forall x \in[c,d] $$
Finally,
since $y_2(x)$ and $ky_1(x)$ have equal values in $[c,d]$, they have equal derivatives there as well; and the uniqueness theorem allows us to infer that $y_2(x)=ky_1(x)$
for all $x$ in $[a,b]$, which concludes the argument. (From G. Simmons book)

Thanks.

Comment: What are the precise hypotheses of your lemma?

Comment: Show that if $c_1y_1(x)+c_2y_2(x)=0$ for all $x\in[-1,1]$, then $c_1=c_2=0$.

Comment: @TedShifrin
Here is the lemma as it is written in the textbook:

If $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$ are two solutions of $$y''+P(x)y'+Q(x)y=0$$ on $[a,b]$, then they are linearly dependent on this interval if and only if their Wronskian $W(y_1,y_2) = y_1y_2'-y_2y_1' $ is identically zero.

Comment: @Gonçalo 
Sorry but can you elaborate more about the relation between showing that $c_1y_1+c_2y_2 = 0$ and $c_1=c_2=0$?
Why do I assume that $c_1y_1+c_2y_2=0$? (Does not this already assumes $y_1$ and $y_2$ are linearly dependent? And we are trying to show otherwise?) Thanks

Comment: Ah, so what is your second-order differential equation, Nero? :)

Comment: You assume $c_1y_1(x)+c_2y_2(x)=0$ for all $x$, Nero. If you show that the *only* solution is $c_1=c_2=0$, then you've established that the two functions are linearly independent. If you find a nontrivial solution, then they are linearly dependent.

Comment: $y_1$ and $y_2$ are linear dependent if there are constants $c_1$ and $c_2$, not both zero, such that $c_1y_1+c_2y_2=0$. On the other hand, if $c_1y_1+c_2y_2=0$ can only be satisfied if $c_1=c_2=0$, then $y_1$ and $y_2$ are linearly independent.

Comment: @TedShifrin, Ohh I get it now! So do you mean that: $c_1x^3+c_2x^2 |x| = 0 $ and to satisfy this only $c_1=c_2=0$ is the possible solution and hence the two functions are linearly independent? What I am not sure about is, if I consider the case $x > 0$ then I can divide by $x^3$ and so $c_1=-c_2$ and not necessarly only 0?, same with the other case $x<0$. Or am I understanding the logic wrong?

Comment: @Gonçalo Oh okay, yes now I see the logical consequence of proving what you said previously. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, so $c_1=-c_2$ is fine for $x>0$. Does it continue to work when $x\le 0$?

Comment: Oh, so if $x<0$ then $c_1=c_2$ meaning, to satisfy both conditions, 
$c_1=c_2=0$ Now I get it thanks a lot @TedShifrin

Comment: Now write an answer. It would be helpful to clarify the statement of the lemma and that no differential equation appears here!

Comment: And, about part (c), we calculated $W=0$ and we showed that the solutions are linearly Independent, so this contradicts the lemma ?

Or do you mean that since no differential equation appears here (in the question), then there does not exist a 2nd order linear differential equation that has these functions as a solution, and so does not contradict the lemma?

Comment: Yes, I will post the proof of the lemma too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using @TedShifrin and @Gonçalo hints and help, here is an (partial) answer:

Part (b):

Assume $$c_1y_1(x)+c_2y_2(x) = 0$$ And, given that $y_1(x)=x^3$ and $y_2(x)=x^2 |x| \space\space\space\space \forall x \in [-1,1]$

**Case 1:** If $x > 0$:

$$c_1x^3+c_2x^3 = 0 \implies c_1=-c_2 \space\space\space\space\space (*)$$
**Case 2:** If $x < 0 $:
$$c_1x^3-c_2x^3=0 \implies c_1=c_2 \space\space\space\space\space\space\space (**)$$

Since $c_1$ and $c_2$ must satisfy $(*)$ and $(**)$ then $c_1=c_2=0$ is the only solution; hence $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$ are linearly independent (By definition).